# Python installer for Windows: disable path length limit option not available

Tags: python

According to [this article](https://aatayyab.wordpress.com/2016/12/25/install-programming-language-python-for-windows-10-64-bit/), when you install Python 3.6 on Windows, the last screen of the installer looks like this:

[image]

I recently had some trouble with long pathnames in Windows, so I was looking for the "Disable path length limit" option in this screen. I installed Python 3.7 on Windows 10, but the "Disable path length limit" option was not visible. 
The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/windows.html?highlight=path%20length%20limit) says nothing about this option.

How can I get this option to appear? Or is it no longer an option in v3.7?

Comment: Did you run the 64-bit installer?

Comment: I think so, but I'll check anyway.

Answer (score 14):

I just updated Python to 3.7.2 and was not prompted and did not remember if I had set MAX_PATH over ride so with regedit navigate to...

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem LongPathsEnabled

If data value is 1 (true) then it is set and Python updates will not ask again.
If 0 (false) then you can change the value in regedit to 1 and you are good to go. [win10]

Comment: I did it and it resolved in vs code but it is still showing up in Jupyter notebook

Comment: excelent. this is the answere

Answer (score 9):

This is not python (or python installer) setting, but a [NTFS filesystem limitation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx#maxpath). 
It can be disabled in windows system settings.  See [this](https://mspoweruser.com/ntfs-260-character-windows-10/) article, or [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/) if you feel advanced enough to manually modify windows registry.

Comment: I'm aware that it's a filesystem limitation. But apparently some Python installers will offer to remove that limitation for you. I'm trying to find out under which circumstances the option appears in the installer.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran that installer, and was shown that option.  After applying that change, the option disappeared.  It's possible that, if the max path length has already been changed, then the option to do so won't be shown.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you already disabled the limit.

Comment: i also think like you

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you only get this option if you start the Installer with admin privileges.

If you start the installer with a non-admin account, it will:

- install Python in that user's directory instead of C:\Program Files
- not prompt for the "disable path length limit" option

So if you accidentally installed Python with a non-admin account and want to disable the path length limit, you can either:

- re-run the installer with an admin account
- directly modify the registry key "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled" and set its value to 1

Both of these require admin privileges.