# Activating "python disable path length limit" option after closing the installation wizard

Tags: python

I forgot to choose this option "python disable path length limit" during the installation and close the installation window.
How can I activate this option now?

Comment: if your in a windows os just reinstall

Comment: My suggestion is to remove Python and reinstall it.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently this option in the Python installer changes a Windows 10 setting to allow longer file paths.

- Run Regedit
- navigate to
  `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem`
  (you can past this into the address bar in Regedit)
- set `LongPathsEnabled` to 1

For more info refer to [Python installer for Windows: disable path length limit option not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51019926/python-installer-for-windows-disable-path-length-limit-option-not-available) and [Python Setup Disabling Path Length Limit Pros and Cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51624449/python-setup-disabling-path-length-limit-pros-and-cons)